# load new content without refresh page, JavaScript after function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$("span.removeFromCart").on("click",function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax.php?id="+id+"&action=remove"         
    })
    .done(function()
    {
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

I have a shopping cart that has - and + next to the quantity of the cart item. it works & updates fine ONLY after location.reload(), as above.

I would like to try and update the content without using the location.reload(), as it causes my toggle cart to hide after reloading the page. Would it be easy to refresh this div or the content on the page without reloading the entire page ?

many thanks

Comment: Right, so, the one you gave us an example is "Remove", so all you'd need to do is remove the item from the cart in the html too, assuming it was successful. No need to reload the whole page.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible, but it seems like you don't understand what it would entail.

In order to update the "toggle", you need to re-render (or re-create it) this can be accomplished with JavaScript templating (like handlebars or underscore template). Or you can refresh just the part of the page that needs updating. You might want to try out something called pjax.

https://github.com/Jrizzi1/pjaxphp